# Target A link using class-name - BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]I want to get the number of paginated pages by getting the text from the A Tags contained within the pagination block :

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import time
from datetime import datetime
import csv

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

# Get category URL
r = requests.get("https://www.sortlist.fr/s/reseaux-sociaux")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for a_tag in soup.find_all('a', class_='s-pb50', href=True):
# The Section containing the pagination contains an A tag with the following class, so it's the parent

  for a_tag in soup.find_all('a', class_='s-underline', href=True):
 # This is where the number is contained

    print(soup.find_all('a', class_='s-underline', href=True))
```

But then the code doesn't return any values or error message! can anyone help? Thanks!!!

The link is : https://www.sortlist.fr/s/reseaux-sociaux

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just go for the `a` tag with class `s-underline` without all those nested loops?

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

# Get category URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.sortlist.fr/s/reseaux-sociaux").content, "html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all("a", class_="s-underline", href=True):
    print(anchor["href"])
```

Output:

```
/sitemap
/explore
https://www.sortlist.fr
https://www.sortlist.fr/explore
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/charte-graphique
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/conseil
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/identite-visuelle
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/publicite
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/redaction
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/strategie-digitale
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/webmarketing
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/communication-globale
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/communication-graphique
https://www.sortlist.fr/s/univers-graphique-de-marque
```

Edit:
The `sl-link` is an attribute of an anchor, so if you want to get all of them try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.sortlist.fr/s/reseaux-sociaux").content, "html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
    try:
        print(f"{anchor['sl-link']}")
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Prints:

```
xx-aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc29ydGxpc3QuZnIv
xx-L2hvdy1pdC13b3Jrcy9jbGllbnQ=
xx-L3N0b3JpZXMvY2xpZW50
xx-L2V4cGxvcmU=
xx-L2hvdy1pdC13b3Jrcy9hZ2VuY3k=
xx-L3N0b3JpZXMvYWdlbmN5
xx-L3ByaWNpbmcvYWdlbmN5
xx-L2FwcGx5P3JlZj1uYXZiYXItYXBwbHk=
xx-L2xvZ2lu
xx-L2hvdy1pdC13b3Jrcy9jbGllbnQ=
xx-L3N0b3JpZXMvY2xpZW50
xx-L2V4cGxvcmU=
xx-L2hvdy1pdC13b3Jrcy9hZ2VuY3k=
xx-L3N0b3JpZXMvYWdlbmN5
xx-L3ByaWNpbmcvYWdlbmN5
xx-L2FwcGx5P3JlZj1uYXZiYXItYXBwbHk=
xx-L2xvZ2lu
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Tag of class `s-pb50` is `<section>` not `<a>`:

```
for a_tag in soup.find('section', class_='s-pb50').find_all('a'):
```

Comment: Actually it gives me more results than wanted. to tweak it for an ID: 

for a_tag in soup.find('section', id_='pagination').find_all('a'):

Did I miss something?

Comment: `id_` should be `id`

Comment: The issue is that keeps on getting values outside of the Section, it's like it doesn't recognize that the Section with the Id "Pagination" is the parent!

Please check the image I uploaded within the original post.